# Выбор определенного элемента из comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Нужно при выборе определенного индекса из comboBox выполнять некий код. Пытался сделать через if, но выдает ошибку при запуске формы.

```
  private void RedactTab_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Добавить Страну");
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(1, "Добавить Город");
            string v = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (v == "0")
            {
                Country();
            }
            else if (v=="1")
            {
                City();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Для начала зачем тут `Insert()` метод, если вы ставите стандартные индексы (0,1 итд)? Почему не просто `comboBox1.Items.Add("Добавить страну");`? Далее я вам посоветую научится проводить отладку вашего кода, поставьте точку остановки на строке `string v` и посмотрите чему равно `SelectedItem`. `Null`? А почему? Да все потому, что по умолчанию `ComboBox` не имеет выбранного элемента, его выбирает либо программа, либо пользователь. Так что же вы хотите получить, если выбора не было? Ставьте тогда перед этой строкой это `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`, тогда первый элемент у вас и выдаст.

Comment: Идем дальше, `SelectedItem` - это не индекс (0,1,2 итд), это объект внутри. То есть в вашем случае он выдаст `Добавить Страну` или `Добавить город`. Если вам надо получить индекс, то используйте `SelectedIndex`, он уже выдаст вам нужную цифру. Ну и последнее - `.ToString()`, зачем?  Если у вас там число будет (если смотреть на вашу проверку `v=="0"`), то в число и преобразуйте! Не надо делать сотни лишний "переконвертирований".

Comment: По поводу самой задачи, вы же понимаете, что ваш код сейчас статичен и отработает только при загрузке элемента? Используйте событие `SelectedIndexChanged` (если нужен индекс) или `SelectedValueChanged` (если нужен сам объект). Подпишитесь на нужное и внутри делайте нужные проверки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за детальное объяснение. Вроде бы теперь все работает.

Comment: Пишите тогда в ответ что сделали.

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким способом.

```
 private void RedactTab_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Добавить Страну");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Добавить Город");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Country();
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                City();
            }
        }
```